# Android Studio app won't start on physical device after updating, but still runs fine on emulator

Tags: java, android, crash, android-emulator

new freelancer dev here.
I've been developing an Android App with Android Studio as apart of some freelance work I've been doing. I do all my testing and debugging on a virtual emulator of an android device while my client reviews the app on his tablet after the testing is done. With this latest version, everything worked perfectly on my emulator, but the app won't even start on my client's tablet. He tried testing the app on a different tablet and while the app runs, it doesn't function properly (Such as buttons not running different methods, crashing after specific inputs, etc.). We are both very confused at what is going on and don't know how to begin tackling this problem. Previous versions of the app work, but they do not have all the required functionality. Nothing major a lot was added or changed from the last version and this most current version. The app has worked on a variety of different emulator settings as well.
I am using the Android Studio built in emulator tools for testing and using Android Studio as my IDE. My app is written in full java while using XML for the layouts of the different pages of the app.
I'm not looking for any immediate fixes/solutions, but more of a general direction to go, because I don't even know how to start fixing this issue.
Also, I'd like to reiterate, previous versions of the app have worked perfectly fine, and all versions of the app work fine on my emulator. The most recent version only fails to start/run properly when run on my client's tablet(s).

I've tried matching my emulator to my client's tablet as closely as possible to try to recreate any potential issues, but I haven't been able to get any of the errors or bugs to appear during debugging. Since we're pretty far apart, I haven't been able to have access to either of the two tablets that he has tried running the app on. My client formatted the original tablet that he was using to test the app but is still having the same issue of the app not starting.

Comment: Variation in android Version could lead to some functions not working as well as crash the app if not handled. Did you check the android version your client tablet running on and have the app tested on the same version

Comment: Yes, both his tablet and my emulator are running the same version, Android 10. This wouldn't have changed between app versions, but thanks for the heads up!